# How do I scale down image to fit the PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: java, android

I have created a PagerSlidingTabStrip and added icons by overriding the method
`getPageIconResId(int position)`. The icon came out to be larger than the PagerSlidingTabStrip in the height direction. As a result, it doesn't get render properly.

Is there a way for me to scale this down to fit within the visible range and to be a reasonable size across all devices????

Comment: Have you added icons in all your drawable folders ?

Comment: yes I have added the icons to the drawable

Comment: According to material design specs, icons should have a size of 24 * 24 dp. Check if your icons exceed this specification.

Comment: Create images of 5 types, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. so android will load image from that particular folder according to Resolution and size of device

Comment: alright but what is these types in term of pixels?

Comment: Open the link :- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Comment: Size of icons in pixels is written before the following topic on the above commented web address, "Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snap, you can refer this

[image]

and for more reference goto this link :-http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html